# Как пересобрать массив с помощью array_reduce или через что то другое?

Tags: php

Из такого

```
$array = [
 0 => ['id'=>332, 'title'=>'Заголовок'],
 1 => ['id'=>338, 'title'=>'Заголовок 2'],
 ...
];
```

Нужно сделать такой

```
$array = [
 322 => ['id'=>332, 'title'=>'Заголовок'],
 338 => ['id'=>338, 'title'=>'Заголовок 2'],
 ...
];
```

Желательно одной строкой через array_reduce или через что то другое

Answer (score 0):

Вот так например:

```
print_r(array_combine(array_column($array, 'id'), $array));
```

Только зачем?

Comment: Для каких-нибудь плагинов в стиле Select2